# Giving Hashmap as input to Mapper instead of a file

Tags: java, regex, hadoop, mapreduce, hashmap

I am writing a MR code to perform Regex pattern match for data that is available in HBASE and HDFS.
My input file is a large CSV file that has the keys to fetch the unique data from HBASE. This input file can have duplicates.

My question - 
In my Main class - I want to read the Input file and perform some processing and hold the data into a hashmap before feeding it to mapper class. 
Of all the examples, I had seen, we can input only file path as input to mapper class, 
is there a way to input an hashmap to mapper instead of a file?

Thank You
Pranay Vyas

Answer (score 0):

Two things:
Map reduce works on the data which is there in HDFS. So your best choice is save your map data as file in HDFS, and move towards map reduce.
However, since your data is coming from HBase, why not use [this](http://hbase.apache.org/book.html#mapreduce.example), and read the data and perform your regex operations on it. Let me know if I missed something

Comment: Thanks Ramzy, I have to process data present on input file. for each record on input file get details from HBASE and HDFS and perform regex scanning.Here is what I did - Passed this input file to mapper class, and inside mapper class I am reading HBASE, HDFS and scanning for regex on documents. post regex found, I update HBASe and SolR index.

Comment: Since the size of my input file is significantly small to create multiple mappers, So I have implemented method to create number of mappers based on the size of input file. max of 12 mapper and min of 1 mapper based on the size and record count.

Comment: Ok. There can be multiple ways to do the same thing. If you were achieving the performance you needed, its all fine. However, number of mappers is decided by framework based on the number of input splits. So unless you said "dont split", or have written your own record reader, I am not sure if its a good practise to control mappers in your code

Comment: Thanks, The control of mappers and the level of control is parameterized in configuration files. My input file is usually less than a block size, so by default, I will always have 1 mapper. Hence Either I write my own split code or control the mappers based on the number of input records. But in overall I am able to achive the performance intended, I am able to Scan 50 documents for 70 regex in 21 sec with 11 mappers.